# configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables qt for android

Tags: android, apk, pyside6

i'm tring to convert pyside6 to android apk on ubuntu
i ran this

```
python3 ./pyside-setup/tools/cross_compile_android/main.py --plat-name=aarch64 --ndk-path=$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT --qt-install-path=/opt/Qt/6.5.0 --sdk-path=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
```

and i get this -
`
100% 812438.0/812438.0 [02:15<00:00, 6008.65it/s]

- export HOST_ARCH=aarch64-linux-android
- HOST_ARCH=aarch64-linux-android
- export TOOLCHAIN=/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin
- TOOLCHAIN=/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin
- export TOOL_PREFIX=/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android
- TOOL_PREFIX=/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android
- export PLATFORM_API=31
- PLATFORM_API=31
- export CXX=/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android31-clang++
- CXX=/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android31-clang++
- export 'CPP=/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android31-clang++ -E'
- CPP='/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android31-clang++ -E'
- export AR=/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-ar
- AR=/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-ar
- export RANLIB=/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-ranlib
- RANLIB=/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-ranlib
- export CC=/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android31-clang
- CC=/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android31-clang
- export LD=/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/ld
- LD=/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/ld
- export READELF=/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-readelf
- READELF=/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-readelf
- export 'CFLAGS=-fPIC -DANDROID'
- CFLAGS='-fPIC -DANDROID'
- ./configure --host=aarch64-linux-android --target=aarch64-linux-android --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --enable-shared --enable-ipv6 ac_cv_file__dev_ptmx=yes ac_cv_file__dev_ptc=no --without-ensurepip ac_cv_little_endian_double=yes
  checking for git... found
  checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  checking host system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-android
  checking for python3.10... python3.10
  checking for python interpreter for cross build... python3.10
  checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
  checking for --with-universal-archs... no
  checking MACHDEP... "linux"
  checking for aarch64-linux-android-gcc... /toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android31-clang
  checking whether the C compiler works... no
  configure: error: in `/tmp/tmp5nxgn8jc/cpython': configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables See` config.log' for more details
  `

i'm tring to convert pyside6 to android apk on ubuntu using qt for android